# Webpack and VueJs CLI v3 – Need relative path for images and web-fonts

Tags: webpack, vue.js, relative-path, vue-cli

Using: Vue CLI 3.0.0-rc.3

How can I config my app, that it is loading the **A) css itself**, **B) the fonts** loaded in css and **C) the images** from a **relative path** depending to the parent-folder the app is located?

My complete vue app is currently running without extra webpack config file. I already know, I would need to create a webpack.config.js, but I don't know what plugins or configuration is necessary.

The app is full functional under absolute path `http:whatever.local/` of course.

But I need to deliver the app complete independent from absolute path, so customer can use it under folder structure he wants and I don't know jet. `http:customerssite.com/i-dont-know-his-structure/vue-app/` (I just don't know).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The described situation contains two different problems:

**1) Relative Path to assets at all.**

To have the web-app functional in every nested folder, you need to load all assets from relative starting point.

**Solution:** baseUrl = './' (the folder itself, were the html starts loading the vue app.)

Documented here: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: './',
}
```

**2) ignore url paths in css-loader**

To be able to use relative paths in the urls used in css for images and fonts, you need to avoid that the css-loader (webpack) is trying to manipulate/controll your used urls.

**Solution:** Configure this css-loader with option `url: false`. And just use the relative url, that starts from the folder were the html starts loading.

Documented here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

```
 module.exports = {
    baseUrl: './',
       css: {
         loaderOptions: {
            css: {
               url: false,
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: When I use `baseUrl: './'` in `vue.config.js` I get an error in the console saying it can't find the favicon.ico file every time I change the route/view (i.e click a link). It seems that it's looking for a new favicon.ico file relative to every route. i.e `/shop` and `/basket` both request new favicons.

Comment: baseUrl is deprecated now and we can now use publicPath instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with [baseUrl](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl) and [assetsDir](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir) parameters

Comment: Change the baseUrl to get relative located web-app running, was the correct hint, of course.
But I had a second issue with the css-loader, that made problems while compiling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called `vue.config.js`
This allow configuration of a public path. Take a look at https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configuration-reference

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '/'
}
```

where the `'/production-sub-path/'` is the relative path to your app